# Display tag and check-box

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, jakarta-ee, displaytag

I need to add checkbox in the display tag table although i did it but still am unable to make it work.

1. Once i check the header checkbox then it should take effect to all the rows in the table
2. Also for selecting individual rows
3. The selected should get deleted while clicking the delete button including from the database.

```xml
<display:table name="sessionScope.results" decorator="com.jobapp.TableDecorator" pagesize="10" requestURI="<%=\"JobServlet?_id=\"+Math.round(Math.random()*1000000)%>">

  <display:column title="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall'/>">
      <input type="checkbox" name="select"  style="margin: 0 0 0 4px" />
  </display:column>

  <display:column property="applicationId" title="Ref. Id" style="width=40px" />
  <display:column property="fullName" title="Full Name" style="width=120px"/>
  <display:column property="dob" title="DOB" style="width=85px"/>

  <display:column property="currentCountry" title="Current Location" style="width=85px"/>
  <display:column property="nationality" title="Nationality" style="width=85px"/>
  <display:column property="email" title="Email" autolink="true"/>
  <display:column property="dateApplied" title="Date Applied" style="width=70px" />
  <display:column property="applicationStatus" title="Status"/>
</display:table>
```

The page displays as expected with the components but figuring out how the logics can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Whether its display-tag 1.1 or 1.2 if its 1.2 you can use the checkboxdecorator class to include checkbox